# Value error and runtime warning error in two-way ANOVA with statsmodels

Tags: python, statsmodels

I want to perform a two-way ANOVA using statsmodels, but I keep getting the errors: `value error (array must not contain infs or NaNs)` and `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars`.

The data looks like this:

[image: The data]

This is the first error:

[image: this is the first error]

This is the expected result:

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please add your code as text to the post and maybe also a portion of your data so we can troubleshoot.